# Set : Prevent insertion of same type

Tags: java, collections, set

I would like to prevent the insertion of an object in a Set if an object of the same type is already in. 
Example :

If i have following class :

```
public class Card{...}
public class Clubs extends Card{...}
public class Diamonds extends Card{...}
public class Hearts extends Card{...}
public class Spades extends Card{...}
```

The behavior should be :

```
Set<Card> cards = new HashSet<>();
System.out.println(cards.add(new Diamonds()) //prints "true"
System.out.println(cards.add(new Spades()) //prints "true"
System.out.println(cards.add(new Spades()) //prints "false"
```

Is there a simple way or a set implementation which can give me this behavior ?

I thought about overriding hashcode/equals for each class extending Card to manage the hashset behavior but I think it is not a reliable solution.

## Edit :

I took the example of a basic deck card but each card is not only a "color", the number of fields, type of fields and methods of each class(Clubs,Diamonds,Spades,Hearts) differs.

## Edit2

This is a more specific definition of my class Card :

```
public abstract class Card
{
    /**Keyword of this card*/
    private final String keyword;

    public Card(String keyword)
    {
         this.keyword = keyword; 
    }

    public abstract void cardDefinition();
    ...
}
```

Here definition of my classes extending card :

```
public class Diamonds extends Card
{
    /**KEYWORD of this card*/
    public static final String KEYWORD = "cell";
    /**Name of this cell*/
    private final int id;
    /**Universe of this cell*/
    private final Universe universe;
    /**Material name of this cell*/
    private final String materialName;

    public Diamonds(int id, Universe universe, String materialName)
    {
        super(KEYWORD);
        this.id = id;
        this.universe = universe;
        this.materialName = materialName;
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public void cardDefinition(){...}
    public void someMethod(OrientedSurface orientedSurface) {...}
    ...
}


public class Spades extends Card
{
    /**keyword of this card*/
    public static final String KEYWORD = "mat";
    /**Name of this material card*/
    private final String name;
    /**Density of this material card*/
    private final double density;'

    public Spades(String name, double density)
    {
        super(KEYWORD);
        this.name = name;
        this.density = density;
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public void cardDefinition(){...}
    public void someMethodBis(Material material) {...}
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: It should return the same hashcode for each object YOU consider equal. Also don't forget to override `equals` the same way, sets also use `equals` .

Comment: So you only want the set to contain the four distinct suits? If so, why not model these as an `enum` instead?

Comment: Each suits are specific and they won't share same methods and same fields, that's why i am not able to use a simple enum.

Comment: I don't think I understand your model well enough; please add more details about your _actual_ class structure. Maybe what you need is a `Map<Suit, CardDetail>` instead. This would allow modeling the `Suit` as an enum and then have the complex details encapsulated within a `CardDetail` object. A map also allows only one value per key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i edited my initial post to give you more details. Your idea with a map seems to fit my needs i will give it a try and get back with a solution if it works. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated answer, perhaps using a mapping of keywords to `Card`s might work for you:

```
Map<String, Card> cards = new HashMap<>();
```

This is assuming that keywords are unique, and that only one card per keyword should be in the map. Storing data in the map could then look like this:

```
Card mySpade = new Spade(...);

if (!cards.contains(Spades.KEYWORD)) {
    cards.put(Spades.KEYWORD, mySpade);
}...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `HashSet` implementation uses the `equals()` respectively `hashCode()` methods of the objects you insert.

In other words: if you want to make that any `Spade` is **equal** to any other `Spade` object - you will have to @Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` accordingly.

Of course - that is a rather wrong design in the first place.

The suits should not be **classes** but [enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). And then you use an **[EnumSet](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/how-to-use-enumset-in-java-with-example.html)**.

In other words, you rather go for:

```
public enum Suit { DIAMONDS, SPADE, ...
```

plus

```
public enum Value { TWO, THREE, ... JOKER ... whatever
```

to then have

```
public class Card {
  private final Suit suit;
  private finale Value value;
```

Meaning: you use enums to create a **type** that enumerates such kinds of values. And then your card objects simply get assigned Suit, Value, ... and so on. And by using enum and EnumSet you basically get the thing you are asking for ... for free.

Finally: good OOP is more than just putting `extends` here or there. Your classes **model** reality. A suit is **not** a card! The suit is a **property** of a card.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and i agree (I edited my post about hashcode/equals). In fact, -i chose an example with a basic deck card but-  my "cards" are not only "colors" they can have many differents parameters (type and numbers of parameters) and my API is based on a single definition of these cards. An enum will not fit my needs because they are not "constant". Is there another way to prevent the insertion of object of same type ?

Comment: Ok with your edit i get your point. I must favor composition over inheritance but how can I get different constructor/methods for each of my suit ? AFAIK enums share their methods with all constants

Comment: @JohannMARTINET Maybe if you update your question with some code example. I am not sure what exactly you are having trouble with.

Comment: I edited my post, i bring a more specific definition of my cards. As you can see, methods/fields/constructor are different for each card. That's why i used inheritance, it can be a mistake ...

Answer (score 0):

Write a dedicated class for the job, which internally uses a set. This class offers a `public` method to add a new card, and before really adding the card to the set it checks if it is allowed. From outside you don't have access to the `private` field containing the set, so you have to use the method that enforces the check.

Comment: Works technically - but misses the crucial point: the SUIT of a card ... isn't a card. He got his whole inheritance hierarchy plain wrong.